# Cucumber feature file closes browser before going to the next feature file

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

When I am running two cucumber feature files, after the first feature file ends, the framework exercises the following -

```
@After("@destroy")
public void shutDown() {
    driverC.quit();
}
```

The browser will die and start up again for the next feature file. I would like the framework to run through all the feature files before exercising the shutdown method...

How do I do this? Many thanks.

Comment: Add the driver.quit code to the Runtime.addshutdownhook() method. Or you can use the SharedWebDriver for a more generic solution -- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/examples/java-webbit-websockets-selenium/src/test/java/cucumber/examples/java/websockets/SharedDriver.java

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Can you give me a more detailed step-by-step on how to implement this? I have never used Runtime.addshutdownhook() and from your github link, the class extends other classes, which I'm not sure what they do. Many thanks my friend. I am new at this, so more detailed the better.

Comment: @noMoreMutants - You just need to duplicate the `SharedWebDriver` code into your test project. It extends an `EventFiringWebDriver` which is like a wrapper on an actual web driver along with giving it some event logging capabilities. This class adds the required shutdown hook as well.